# Problem with Build constructor while setting up android notifications

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried setting up notifications in my android application, but I just can't figure it out. This is my code:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warr)
                        .setContentTitle("Upozorenje")
                        .setContentText("Narusena socijalna distanca")
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                        .build();
```

I get the following error
Cannot resolve constructor 'Builder(anonymous android.os.Handler.Callback, java.lang.String)'
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `this` needs to be a `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`. Your code is inside of a `Handler.Callback`, so `this` is not a `Context`.

Comment: Uh yes, I get it. I just replaced this with getApplicationContext() and i dont get this error. Thank you